# React-admin CheckboxGroupInput check some checkboxes by default

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

how to make some checkboxes checked by default

```
    <CheckboxGroupInput
      source="my_junction_table"
      choices={choices}
      optionText={<KioskCheckbox />}
      initialValue={[{ id: 4, checked: true }]}  // don't work
      defaultValue={[{ id: 4, checked: true }]}  // don't work
      options={{ checked: true }}                // check all
      optionValue="id"
    />
```

with

```
options={{ checked: true }}
```

all the checkboxes are checked

with

```
initialValue={[{ id: 4, checked: true, value: true }]}
defaultValue={[{ id: 4, checked: true }]}
```

nothing work, I've already see the doc and the code in react-admin repo, can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Shevchuk Slavik is almost worked, just need to replace 'initialValue' prop by 'defaultValue'.
Then create 'choices' props like this:

`choices={[ { id: 'create',  checked: true }, { id: 'update'}, { id: 'approve'} ]}`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem last week.
The initialValue should be an array with identifiers, the object array will not work.
I solved it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {CheckboxGroupInput} from 'react-admin';

export const CheckboxGroupInputMod = (props, {checkedProp = 'checked'}) => {
    let initialValue = [];
    props.choices.map(value => {
        if (value[checkedProp]) initialValue.push(value.id);
    })

    return <CheckboxGroupInput {...props} initialValue={initialValue} />;
}

export default CheckboxGroupInputMod;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the choice list you made is as follows,

you can write down the `id` of the item you want to select at the `initialValue` props.

```
const choices = [
  { id: 'm', name: 'Male' },
  { id: 'f', name: 'Female' }
];
```

If you want to choose both Male and Female, you can do the following.

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
  source="my_junction_table"
  choices={choices}
  initialValue={['m', 'f']}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On `"react-admin": "^4.14.0"`, I'm using the following approach to achieve the result.

```
const lensEraChoices = [
  { id: "Modern", name: "Modern" },
  { id: "Vintage", name: "Vintage" },
];
```

...

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
  source="lensEra"
  choices={lensEraChoices}
  onChange={handleChoicesChange}
  validate={validateCheckboxGroup}
  defaultValue={["Modern"]} //<---- Checks this option by default
 />
```